# What is a gradient matrix?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I know what the gradient of a function is, but I have this problem which seems to have something else in mind.

The problem reads

> Write the oscillator equation $y''-\cos y=0$ as a system of first-order equations with $x_1=y$ and $x_2=y'$ and find the gradient matrix $\nabla f$, and compute its eigenvalue as a function of $x$.  Draw some typical trajectories in phase space and indicate where you expect divergence, based on eigenvalue analysis.

Does this just mean to turn the system into a matrix like

$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}'=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0\\-\cos x_1\end{pmatrix}$$

Would the coefficient matrix be the gradient matrix?  Or would it be the fundamental matrix solution?  I've tried googling the term and nothing seems to be what this problem is referring to.

Comment: Are you taking the gradient with respect to scalars or another matrix.

Comment: @aleden great question, I have no idea.  The only concepts of gradient I understand is that of the derivative and the vector of partial derivatives.  In this, it seems like you take a gradient of some function, but in some mysterious way it's related to a system of equations.  But I'm only saying what's fairly obvious from the information I posted above.

Comment: a gradient is a tensor outer product of something with $\nabla$ if it is a 0-tensor (scalar) it becomes a 1-tensor (vector), if it is a 1-tensor it becomes a 2-tensor (matrix) - in other words it increases in size by one index. since it is not given in the problem what this mysterious f is, it is a bit difficult to help.

Comment: I think you might be looking to take the gradient with respect to $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ but I am not quite sure. Maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Derivatives_with_matrices) can help you.

Comment: @Addem: Do you mean Jacobian matrix, critical points and the phase portrait?

Comment: @Moo I don't know--I know what the Jacobian is, but don't know how it's related to the phase portrait.  If they're related that's probably good reason to think the Jacobian is the intended concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first order system has a sign error, it should read as 
$$
\binom{\dot x_1}{\dot x_2}=F(x_1,x_2)=\binom{x_2}{\cos x_1}
$$
The gradient matrix you are to compute is now the Jacobian matrix of $F$. For that task, you can forget the context of a differential equation and just compute the partial derivatives
$$
F'(x)=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-\sin x_1&0\end{pmatrix}.
$$